# "accounts" in bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core-accounts

I've read (i.e. here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained) about the concept of "accounts" in bitcoin.  However I can't see how to create them in `bitcoin-qt`.   How do I use accounts?

Answer (score 1):

The accounts feature is only accessible through the RPC interface.

Also, unless you want to maintain separate balances for several users sharing the same wallet, it's unlikely you'll want to use this feature.